# MissingMethodException: how to understand in which assembly the method missing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

Assembly "A.dll" depends on the "Do()" method in assembly "B.dll".

During execution, a MissingMethodException occurred in assembly "A.dll" because the method "Do()" was not found

How can I reliably determine which "B.dll" assembly .NET was trying to find a method in?

After all, he can try to search both in "B.dll" 1.0.0.0 and in "B.dll" 2.0.0.0

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example. otherwise how do you expect us to help?

Comment: You can enable the Fusion Log or run the Sysinternals Process Explorer tool to determine the path from which B.dll was loaded.